# How to use require() and export an object instantiated from a function, along with prototype methods?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, prototype, require

Here's the code I'm trying to get work:

```
var SomeObj = function() {
    this.name = 'john';
};


SomeObj.protoype = {
    initialize: function() { }
};

module.exports = SomeObj;
```

but all I get the object instantiated from the function, and the name property, but no initialize or other methods attached to the prototype like you would normally get.

Comment: You're exporting the constructor, there's no problem here. When you require it you'd have to use `new`

Comment: Why would you want to export an instance instead of the constructor? If you want to export a singleton, you shouldn't use the constructor+prototype pattern at all.

Comment: @elclanrs thats what I thought, but here's the error message I get: http://snapplr.com/h8rb ...i'm developer for github's Atom editor.

Comment: i think it's actually CommonJS being used since that's what Node uses. maybe that behaves differently.

Comment: jesus, i spelled prototype wrong, that was all it was.

Answer (score 0):

here's how I defined mine for exporting for RequireJS

```
define(
        "SomeObj",
        function(require, exports, modules) {

            var SomeObj= function() {
                //declare attributes and methods to be executed here

            };


            SomeObj.prototype.initialize = function() {
                //all your other method references
            };

            SomeObj.prototype.constructor = SomeObj;

            return SomeObj;

});
```